# Best practice for sequential execution of group of tasks in Celery

Tags: django, celery, python-3.5

I have page that allows user to select tasks which should be executed in selected order, one by one. So, it create group of tasks. User can create several of them. For each group I should make possible to look on tasks progress.

I'm looked into several things like `chain`, `chord`, `group` but it seems very tricky for me, and I don't see any possibility to look on each task progress.

What's good solution for this kind of problem?

Comment: You may try to add a separate queue for each user and then limit the number of concurrent tasks on those queues to 1.

Comment: @skovorodkin, it seems like a different case. In simplest case I have only one user who can start different group of tasks. And groups, and tasks in them, must executes sequentially in order of them appearance

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would use a model. The user selects the tasks and orders them, creating records in the table. A celery task runs and executes the tasks from the table in the specified order.